# Rails javascript; alert to fire when leaving a field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

My ultimate goal is to add some validation to a set of `date fields`. However, my javascript sucks, so I'm starting small.
I am starting out by trying to get an alert message when a user leaves a field.
(For simplicity I'm just doing it all in my view...) Heres what I go to work...

```
    # html.erb-template
    <div class="from_date">
      From Date
<input type="text" id="from_date" name="from_date"></input>
    </div>

    <script>
      $("#from_date").blur( function() {
        alert("boom!"); 
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm quite confused, maybe I'm misunderstanding. You say you want to have an event fire when you "leave" a field, but your implementation and ernd enson's answer both implement the "focus" event, which fires when an element gains focus (meaning opposite of losing or leaving focus). To me it sounds like you're looking for the [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event instead, non?

Comment: Me thinks you are correct. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine - problem is that `class` and `id` are named the same, but you want to watch the input field not the surrounding div.

I just made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkP35/1) from your script and changed

1. the listener to be attached to the `input field`'s id - and it's working.
2. the `alert` into a `console.log`

see

```
$("#from_date").blur(function() {.....
// instead of 
$(".from_date").blur(function() {.....
```

Comment: OK, that gets me a little closer, going to update my code above. Thanx!

Comment: Now the code in your question does, what it is intended too. So this question will not help anybody again. I strongly recommend not to change the code in a question - but it is yours.